# ListView inside ExpansionTile doesn't work

Tags: listview, dart, flutter, flutter-sliver

listview is not working inside ExpansionTile

i have tried to show a listview.builder inside ExpansionTile but it throws some exceptions

```
Card(
       child: ExpansionTile(
           leading: Icon(
              Icons.stars,
              color: Colors.pinkAccent,
           ),
           title: Text('Reviews',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                          ),
                children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 5,
                        itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                          return (Text('item $i'));
                     })
                   ],
             ),
     ),
```

i want to achieve like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv074.jpg

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8182): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter ( 8182): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter ( 8182): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
I/flutter ( 8182): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter ( 8182): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
I/flutter ( 8182): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
I/flutter ( 8182): there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
I/flutter ( 8182): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
I/flutter ( 8182): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
I/flutter ( 8182):
```

Comment: add `shrinkWrap: true,` in `ListView.builder`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The vertical size of your `ListView` is unbounded which makes it impossible to render. Set the [`shrinkWrap`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html) property of `ListView` to `true` to work around that.

Comment: thank it works but it throws this exception every time i scroll over ExpansionTile ```` [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 8182): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 96 pos 7: 'positions.isNotEmpty': PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with it.
E/flutter ( 8182): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:40:39)
E/flutter ( 8182): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:36:5) ```

Comment: this is the exception again `[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 8182): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 96 pos 7: 'positions.isNotEmpty': PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with it.
E/flutter ( 8182): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:40:39)
E/flutter ( 8182): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:36:5)`

Comment: This must be something else in your UI. I can't see a `PageView` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 14):

None of the above solution doesn't work as expected. So I have solved the issue. You need to use this in **Listview.builder()** inside **ExpansionTile** children:

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Full Code:

```
                ExpansionTile( 
                    onExpansionChanged: (e){
                      //Your code
                    },
                    title: Text("You title text"),
                    children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                     shrinkWrap: true,
                     physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                     itemCount: items.length,
                     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                     return Text(items[index]);
                      }
                   )
                      
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: @RudyRudy glad to help :)

Comment: wouldn't shrink wrap and never scroll make listview useless ? there is no scrollabality inside listview and shrink wraps makes listview load all elements at once

Comment: i tried this way to build my expansion tile, but when my ```item.length``` become larger, it will take some time to build it. Is there any way to help improve the performance?

Answer (score 2):

I try many ways, finally I found solution.

Use this code instread of ListView.Builder.

```
   ...List.generate(plist.length, (index) {

              return  Text('Text');
            }),
```

Answer (score 1):

Add both shrinkwrap and controller to ListView.builder

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();


    ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
           shrinkWrap: true,
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve use `shrinkWrap: true,` in `ListView` parameter.